# rosmake can't find my packages

Tags: ros, rosmake, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.
I've been going through a lot of tutorials and online projects to get more familiar with ros, and haven't been having problems. I recently loaded the tum_ardrone packege which includes running

`` export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/ardrone_autonomy ``

since then, whenever I use rosmake I get the error

`[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['learning_ps3joy/']`

`[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.`

I've seen people ask this question, and the answer is to run some sort of export command like the one above, but I'm unclear about how to do it, and why i never had this problem before.
I have also seen a lot about the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, and wanted to know if anyone could tell me how to see what it is on my computer, how to change it, and how to make sure packages I'm making are on it, if that makes sense?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188173/rosmake-can%27t-find-my-packages/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know why you're getting this error, your `export` command looks right to me. Anyway, as you said, probably something is wrong with ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

Please open a new terminal and type the following command:

`echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`

This command will return the current paths that ROS looks for packages when you call commands such as `rosmake`.
Check if in the output it's included the path for your packages.

If not, try using the command `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`. After that, open a new terminal a try the first command again, the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH should have changed back for its default value.

Finally, try using the `rosmake` command again.

---

Originally posted by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) with karma: 53 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0